# How to avoid printing line numbers with data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Printing a `data.table` adds a number for each line of output before the actual output, e.g.

```
> DT <- data.table(cbind(1:3,3:1))
> DT
    V1 V2
 1:  1  3
 2:  2  2
 3:  3  1
> print(DT)
    V1 V2
 1:  1  3
 2:  2  2
 3:  3  1
```

How can I avoid printing the "1:", "2:", "3:" before the data rows? I would like write html- or latex-formated output of my data using `xtable`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`print.data.table` has an argument `row.names`, which is set to TRUE by default. Just use

```
> print(DT, row.names=FALSE)
 V1 V2
  1  3
  2  2
  3  1
```

Comment: Is there also a way to get rid of the row names when I want to process the data.table further, e.g. in `xtable(DT)`?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to supress the names in `xtable()` output, you need to use
the arguments to `print.xtable()`:

```
library(xtable)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 3:1)
xtable(df)

## % latex table generated in R 3.0.2 by xtable 1.7-1 package
## % Wed Apr  9 06:53:55 2014
## \begin{table}[ht]
## \centering
## \begin{tabular}{rrr}
##   \hline
##  & x & y \\ 
##   \hline
## 1 &   1 &   3 \\ 
##   2 &   2 &   2 \\ 
##   3 &   3 &   1 \\ 
##    \hline
## \end{tabular}
## \end{table}

print(xtable(df), include.rownames = FALSE)

## % latex table generated in R 3.0.2 by xtable 1.7-1 package
## % Wed Apr  9 06:53:55 2014
## \begin{table}[ht]
## \centering
## \begin{tabular}{rr}
##   \hline
## x & y \\ 
##   \hline
##   1 &   3 \\ 
##     2 &   2 \\ 
##     3 &   1 \\ 
##    \hline
## \end{tabular}
## \end{table}
```

In this case it doesn't matter that you're using a data.table instead of a data.frame